# How do I perform row call using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

I have done a bit of research on how I can perform a rowcall using google app script but have a little challenge and will appreciate any assitance on this.

So this code looks at the first column and gets the values to be used in renaming new tabs

```
function newSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("main")
    var getNames = sheet1.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
        var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
        if (copy) {
            Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
        } else {
            templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
            ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
        }
    }
}
```

The sheet

[image]

What I would like to do and is becoming a challenge, is While creating a new tab with a name then, I would like to copy the entire row to the new tab/sheet. e.g for the sheet **Levi** only the raw with Levi Data be copied to the sheet.

At the moment my code copies the entire source sheet to the new tabs/sheets. I will really appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Proposed solution:

Now you are using the main sheet as a template so when you use it with the function `.copyTo` you will copy the whole content.
You will have to get the whole row corresponding to the index of the given name.

### Approach

You will need an extra filtering to get the correct row values you want to put in the new sheet.
I will filter the name column (column A) and get the index of the name in the loop.

(I am assuming you can have some gaps so the index of the for loop would not be enough).

Once i found the corresponding index i will need to increment it by one because row indexing starts from 1 in Google Spreadsheets.

Now i can easily get the row using the function `.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`.
I am using the function `.getLastColumn()` to compute the `numColumns` parameter.

Now I can use the function `.appendRow()` to insert the row in the new sheet I just created with the `.insertSheet()` function.

### Sample Code:

```
function newSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("main")
    var getNames = sheet1.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
        var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
        if (copy) {
            Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
        } else {
            //The copyTo function will copy the entire sheet
            //templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);

            var rowIndex = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues().flatMap(value => value[0]).indexOf(getNames[i]) + 1;
            var rowValues = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
            ss.insertSheet(getNames[i]).appendRow(rowValues[0]);

            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
            ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

In the case the names are repeated you will have to filter the column and extract the corresponding indexes.

First you will have to get a set for your getNames variable. (otherwise you will have repetitions).

```
var getNames = [...new Set(sheet1.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(","))];
```

Then you will have to map the row indexes to the names in the column A.
Now you can filter by the getNames values and you will obtain the row indexes.
In the end you can append to the new sheet the rows at the corresponding indexes.

```
var rowIndexes = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues()
                                       .map((value, index) => [value[0], (index + 1)])
                                       .filter(value => value[0] === getNames[i]);
var namedSheet = ss.insertSheet(getNames[i]);
rowIndexes.map(index => {
                 var rowValues = sheet1.getRange(index[1], 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
                 namedSheet.appendRow(rowValues[0]);
});
```

### References:

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Many thanks, Alessandro, this code saved me a lot of time. Kindly advice me on this. What if for instance, several rows have John in the first column but different data in the other columns and I want to have all John's data in one sheet/tab, same case to other people who appear severally in the source sheet, what is the best way to go about it. Again sorry for the bother, am still new in Javascript and trying  to do a bit of automation.

Comment: Hello @Just, in this case you will have to filter your array. 
First you will have to get a set for your getNames variable. (otherwise you will have repetitions).

Comment: I edited my answer with a working solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Alessandro. This is well illustrated and understandable. I have made edits to my code as well and works fine. Cheers

Comment: Hey Alesandro, been modify the code so that Instead of saying "Sheet already exists" it should just overwrite the sheet with a similar name and also include the first row on copying data so that there are titles..but each time I ran the code it still says "sheet exists" mind helping out a brother, please?